# Simple HTTP server for folders

Tags: http, http-server

Every once in a while when I'm debugging some web app, it would be useful for me to be able to serve a folder via a lightweight HTTP server. Something along the lines of

```
cd folder
httpserve -p 5000
```

in order to serve that folder over port 5000. Is there any tool to allow me to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, the Python thing from ax25 seems to work great for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5000`

Or for cgi serving:

`python -m CGIHTTPServer 5000`

and browse to : `http://localhost:5000/myscript.py`

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad to have one to answer!